# Imagemagick - Trim SVG canvas to fit

Tags: svg, imagemagick, mogrify

I have a collection of SVGs that seem to not have their canvas fit to their size. Therefore, they seem to be off centered. I can import them into Sketch, then export them again as an SVG. Sketch will take the SVG and trim the canvas so the SVG has a very tiny padding value. It does exactly what I want (labor intensive), however, I would like to determine how to do this programmatically.

I am using the SVGs from this repo: https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons

The command I execute: `mogrify -density 3600 -extent 1100x1100 -gravity center -background none -format png *.svg`

Here is a sample PNG after converting the SVG, with mogrify:
[image]

Here is a sample PNG after exporting through Sketch, then converting:
[image]

Comment: Do you realise that ImageMagick will rasterise your images and they will no longer be vector images that can be resized without *"jaggies"* for example?

Comment: Yes because the platform I need them for does not support SVGs. As long as I keep the source svgs, I should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your close, but need to perform a trim operation before extending the canvas. In fact, `-gravity center -extent 1100x1100` should be the last operation.

```
mogrify -density 3600 -background none -fill white \
        -trim -gravity center -extent 1100x1100 \
        -format png wi-thunderstorm.svg
```

[image: wi-thunderstorm.png]

Although swapping `-density` with `-size` might prove more consistent with Sketch.

```
 mogrify -size 1100x1100 -background none -fill white \
         -trim -gravity Center -extent 1100x1100 \
         -format png wi-thunderstorm.svg
```

Comment: So I was trying this, `mogrify -trim +repage -density 3600 -extent 1100x1100 -gravity center -background none -format png *.svg`

Comment: are you able to get the `-fill white` to actually work?

Comment: No issue for me with `-fill white`. The styles of the SVG paths are not defined, so setting the fill, stroke, & background attributes before reading the SVG should inherit.

Comment: When I use `-verbose`, I don't see the fill being executed at all - just background color.

Answer (score 1):

This command will take all the SVG files in the current directory, trim them to within a millimetre of their lives and then add a 10px transparent border to all sides:

```
mogrify -format png -trim -bordercolor none -border 10 +repage  *svg
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you ever wanted to recenter the actual SVGs in code, here's how you could do it.

This is in Javascript.  So you could write something like a headless Chrome script.  Or for instance you could convert this to Java and use Batik.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("recenter");

// Get the real bounding box of the icon shape
var bbox = svg.getBBox();

// Get the viewBox width and height
var viewBox_width = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
var viewBox_height = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height;

// Recenter the contents
svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = bbox.x - (viewBox_width - bbox.width) / 2;
svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = bbox.y - (viewBox_height - bbox.height) / 2;
```

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 30 30;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M4.63,16.91c0,1.11,0.33,2.1,0.99,2.97s1.52,1.47,2.58,1.79l-0.66,1.68c-0.03,0.14,0.02,0.22,0.14,0.22h2.13l-0.98,4.3h0.28
 l3.92-5.75c0.04-0.04,0.04-0.09,0.01-0.14c-0.03-0.05-0.08-0.07-0.15-0.07h-2.18l2.48-4.64c0.07-0.14,0.02-0.22-0.14-0.22h-2.94
 c-0.09,0-0.17,0.05-0.23,0.15l-1.07,2.87c-0.71-0.18-1.3-0.57-1.77-1.16c-0.47-0.59-0.7-1.26-0.7-2.01c0-0.83,0.28-1.55,0.85-2.17
 c0.57-0.61,1.27-0.97,2.1-1.07l0.53-0.07c0.13,0,0.2-0.06,0.2-0.18l0.07-0.51c0.11-1.08,0.56-1.99,1.37-2.72
 c0.81-0.73,1.76-1.1,2.85-1.1c1.09,0,2.04,0.37,2.85,1.1c0.82,0.73,1.28,1.64,1.4,2.72l0.07,0.58c0,0.11,0.06,0.17,0.18,0.17h1.6
 c0.91,0,1.68,0.32,2.32,0.95c0.64,0.63,0.97,1.4,0.97,2.28c0,0.85-0.3,1.59-0.89,2.21c-0.59,0.62-1.33,0.97-2.2,1.04
 c-0.13,0-0.2,0.06-0.2,0.18v1.37c0,0.11,0.07,0.17,0.2,0.17c1.33-0.04,2.46-0.55,3.39-1.51s1.39-2.11,1.39-3.45
 c0-0.9-0.22-1.73-0.67-2.49c-0.44-0.76-1.05-1.36-1.81-1.8c-0.77-0.44-1.6-0.66-2.5-0.66H20.1c-0.33-1.33-1.04-2.42-2.11-3.26
 s-2.3-1.27-3.68-1.27c-1.41,0-2.67,0.44-3.76,1.31s-1.79,1.99-2.1,3.36c-1.11,0.26-2.02,0.83-2.74,1.73S4.63,15.76,4.63,16.91z
  M12.77,26.62c0,0.39,0.19,0.65,0.58,0.77c0.01,0,0.05,0,0.11,0.01c0.06,0.01,0.11,0.01,0.14,0.01c0.17,0,0.33-0.05,0.49-0.15
 c0.16-0.1,0.27-0.26,0.32-0.48l2.25-8.69c0.06-0.24,0.04-0.45-0.07-0.65c-0.11-0.19-0.27-0.32-0.5-0.39
 c-0.17-0.02-0.26-0.03-0.26-0.03c-0.16,0-0.32,0.05-0.47,0.15c-0.15,0.1-0.26,0.25-0.31,0.45l-2.26,8.72
 C12.78,26.44,12.77,26.53,12.77,26.62z M16.93,23.56c0,0.13,0.03,0.26,0.1,0.38c0.14,0.22,0.31,0.37,0.51,0.44
 c0.11,0.03,0.21,0.05,0.3,0.05s0.2-0.02,0.32-0.08c0.21-0.09,0.35-0.28,0.42-0.57l1.44-5.67c0.03-0.14,0.05-0.23,0.05-0.27
 c0-0.15-0.05-0.3-0.16-0.45s-0.26-0.26-0.46-0.32c-0.17-0.02-0.26-0.03-0.26-0.03c-0.17,0-0.33,0.05-0.47,0.15
 c-0.14,0.1-0.24,0.25-0.3,0.45l-1.46,5.7c0,0.02,0,0.05-0.01,0.11C16.93,23.5,16.93,23.53,16.93,23.56z"/>
</svg>

<svg id="recenter" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 30 30;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M4.63,16.91c0,1.11,0.33,2.1,0.99,2.97s1.52,1.47,2.58,1.79l-0.66,1.68c-0.03,0.14,0.02,0.22,0.14,0.22h2.13l-0.98,4.3h0.28
 l3.92-5.75c0.04-0.04,0.04-0.09,0.01-0.14c-0.03-0.05-0.08-0.07-0.15-0.07h-2.18l2.48-4.64c0.07-0.14,0.02-0.22-0.14-0.22h-2.94
 c-0.09,0-0.17,0.05-0.23,0.15l-1.07,2.87c-0.71-0.18-1.3-0.57-1.77-1.16c-0.47-0.59-0.7-1.26-0.7-2.01c0-0.83,0.28-1.55,0.85-2.17
 c0.57-0.61,1.27-0.97,2.1-1.07l0.53-0.07c0.13,0,0.2-0.06,0.2-0.18l0.07-0.51c0.11-1.08,0.56-1.99,1.37-2.72
 c0.81-0.73,1.76-1.1,2.85-1.1c1.09,0,2.04,0.37,2.85,1.1c0.82,0.73,1.28,1.64,1.4,2.72l0.07,0.58c0,0.11,0.06,0.17,0.18,0.17h1.6
 c0.91,0,1.68,0.32,2.32,0.95c0.64,0.63,0.97,1.4,0.97,2.28c0,0.85-0.3,1.59-0.89,2.21c-0.59,0.62-1.33,0.97-2.2,1.04
 c-0.13,0-0.2,0.06-0.2,0.18v1.37c0,0.11,0.07,0.17,0.2,0.17c1.33-0.04,2.46-0.55,3.39-1.51s1.39-2.11,1.39-3.45
 c0-0.9-0.22-1.73-0.67-2.49c-0.44-0.76-1.05-1.36-1.81-1.8c-0.77-0.44-1.6-0.66-2.5-0.66H20.1c-0.33-1.33-1.04-2.42-2.11-3.26
 s-2.3-1.27-3.68-1.27c-1.41,0-2.67,0.44-3.76,1.31s-1.79,1.99-2.1,3.36c-1.11,0.26-2.02,0.83-2.74,1.73S4.63,15.76,4.63,16.91z
  M12.77,26.62c0,0.39,0.19,0.65,0.58,0.77c0.01,0,0.05,0,0.11,0.01c0.06,0.01,0.11,0.01,0.14,0.01c0.17,0,0.33-0.05,0.49-0.15
 c0.16-0.1,0.27-0.26,0.32-0.48l2.25-8.69c0.06-0.24,0.04-0.45-0.07-0.65c-0.11-0.19-0.27-0.32-0.5-0.39
 c-0.17-0.02-0.26-0.03-0.26-0.03c-0.16,0-0.32,0.05-0.47,0.15c-0.15,0.1-0.26,0.25-0.31,0.45l-2.26,8.72
 C12.78,26.44,12.77,26.53,12.77,26.62z M16.93,23.56c0,0.13,0.03,0.26,0.1,0.38c0.14,0.22,0.31,0.37,0.51,0.44
 c0.11,0.03,0.21,0.05,0.3,0.05s0.2-0.02,0.32-0.08c0.21-0.09,0.35-0.28,0.42-0.57l1.44-5.67c0.03-0.14,0.05-0.23,0.05-0.27
 c0-0.15-0.05-0.3-0.16-0.45s-0.26-0.26-0.46-0.32c-0.17-0.02-0.26-0.03-0.26-0.03c-0.17,0-0.33,0.05-0.47,0.15
 c-0.14,0.1-0.24,0.25-0.3,0.45l-1.46,5.7c0,0.02,0,0.05-0.01,0.11C16.93,23.5,16.93,23.53,16.93,23.56z"/>
</svg>
```